# Add static header (vertical) scrollable view to gridview

Tags: android

I want to add static header(scrollable) to a gridview.

In Listview I do this using `addHeader` method.

Does the gridvew have a method like a `addHeader`? (I could not find it) Or if not, how can I do this using another option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to make a separate layout for the scrollable header, and park it on top of your gridview in a linear or relative layout. That's the way I'd do it, anyway.